# Start new bash session background

Tags: bash, alias

Is it possible to create a command called `new_bash` that allows me to do the following?

```
new_bash alias test="ls"
new bash alias new_command="ls"

new_bash test
file1
new_bash new_command
file1
```

Comment: You'd have to somehow spawn the new bash in background, then have the `new_bash` command communicate with it. Doable, slightly tricky, probably the easiest way uses a FIFO.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Are the aliases only supposed to be defined for future subshells, not the current shell?

Comment: @chepner a shell within a shell.  Basically a way to avoid rewriting bad implementations of a shell.

Comment: But what's the point of the `new_bash` command? You can already start a new shell by running `bash`. When that shell exits, you return to the original shell.

Comment: @chepner It is supposed to reference a shell running in the background. PSkocik gets the intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
##Background:

cd $(mktemp -d)
> file1

##Setup state (background bash + pipe)
pipeDir=$(mktemp -d)
mkfifo $pipeDir/p #pipe for communicating with the shell
#start the shell in the background, make it read from the pipe, and disable I/O buffering
stdbuf -i0 -o0 bash < $pipeDir/p & 
#open the pipe from the other end on fd 3 (or another fd)
exec 3>$pipeDir/p && 
rm -rf "$pipeDir" #don't need the directory or the physical link to the pipe anymore

##Now you can communicate with the shell
echo ls >&3
#Ouptuts: file1

#This is how you end it all
exec 3>&-
```

Your function would need to maintain global state.
Your function would need to check if the state has been set up and set it up if it hasn't been (by checking for the existence of a variable, perhaps).
After the setup or if the state exists, it only needs to `echo` its arguments (`"$@"`) to `&3` or whatever file descriptor you open the pipe on.

It might be a better idea to make three functions (it will be a tiny bit more efficient):

```
init_new_bash
new_bash
end_new_bash
```

Example (needs better signal handling):

```
#!/bin/sh 
#^will work in bash also
init_new_bash(){
    set -e #all must succeed
    pipeDir=$(mktemp -d)  
    mkfifo "$pipeDir/p" 

    stdbuf -i0 -o0 bash < "$pipeDir"/p & 
    bashPid=$! 

    exec 3>"$pipeDir/p"
    rm -rf "$pipeDir" 
    set +e
}
new_bash(){ echo "$@" >&3; }
end_new_bash(){ exec 3>&-; wait "$bashPid"; }

##Test run:
init_new_bash && {

   new_bash echo hello world
   new_bash ls

end_new_bash;}
```

Comment: Stuff like this confirms how little I really understand unix.

Comment: It may seem daunting, but it's all really simple. Feel free to ask if you don't understand something in it.

Comment: Do you mind creating the init_new_bash,
new_bash,
end_new_bash commands because I can't get your example to work.

Comment: I've added an example implementation.

Comment: What shell are you on I get `: not found `

Comment: Try replacing the shebang line with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. (You may need to focus on basics of shell scripting some more if you're getting these types of problems. )

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  What distro are you own I'm on debian.

Comment: You've probably got some stray non-ascii character in your script.

Comment: I got your original partially work, but the following doesn't work `echo "alias test1='echo test1'" >&3;echo "test1" >&3`.  It doesn't appear to be referring to the same open shell wherever it might be.

Comment: Do you have it in a script? Aliases don't work in scripts unless you specifically allow them.

Comment: I'm happy to add a 50 point bounty of the little rep I have but as of right your script doesn't work with alias's like I would expect it would.

Comment: To expand aliases in bash scripts, do `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Comment: Thanks but where do I use such a command.  It's not a bash option so it isn't clear to me what to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28823/discussion-between-pskocik-and-liam-william).

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking looks very similar to a simple [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html).

Whenever you use encapsulate your commands using parenthesis, e.g. `(ls)`, this command will be run in a child process of the current shell.

For your example:

```
( 
alias test='ls'
alias new_command='ls'
test
new_command
)
```

Or, since aliases are copied to subshells

```
alias test='ls'
alias new_command='ls'
( test ) # one subshell
( new_command ) # another subshell
```

If you need that your commands run in the same subshell:

```
alias test='ls'
alias new_command='ls'
( test ; new_command ) # same subshell
```

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I am looking for.  I would the commands to keep a memory.

Comment: When you execute then in a single subshell they run in the same scope